# How to correctly convert factor to numeric in a new dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I convert factor to numeric in my dataset as below

```
library(dplyr) 
df = data.frame(level= c( 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'very high'))

df$level = as.numeric(revalue(df$level, c('low' = 1, 'medium' =2, 'high'= 3, 'very high'=4)))
df
```

It's ok.
The problem arises when I try to apply this rule for new dataset (I traned the model & and want to predict a new data)

```
newdude = data.frame(level = c( 'high'))
newdude$level = as.numeric(revalue(newdude$level, c('low' = 1, 'medium' =2, 'high'= 3, 'very high'=4)))
Error
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: low, medium, very high 
> newdude
  level
1     1
```

I get '1' instead of '3'
I can not make for ample

```
newdude$level = as.numeric(revalue(newdude$level, c( 'high'= 3)))
```

because I can not know in advance what value it will take

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead

```
newdude = data.frame(level = factor('high', levels = c('low', 'medium', 'high', 'very high')))

newdude$level
[1] high
Levels: low medium high very high
as.numeric(newdude$level)
[1] 3
```

Comment: thanx  @Rui please help how to specify `levels` loading csv

Comment: sorry i've done `newdude = data.frame(level = c( 'high'))` and then `newdude$level = factor(newdude$level, levels = c('low', 'medium', 'high', 'very high'))`